# What-I-am-doing for compiling DBASE.C for Lua

Tags: lua

friend.

I need instructions for compiling this utility. But I can not find info.

My current scenario is Win7, Lua 5.1 (because it is installed in my machine by my son, but later I'll try with Lua v5.3.## current).

I have seen on a txt file this command:

```
gcc string.c dbf_head.c dbf_ndx.c dbf_misc.c dbf_rec.c luadbase.c -shared -O2 -Wall -L/usr/local/lib -llua -ldl -lm -lnsl -o dbase.so
```

As I understand that /usr/local/lib is a Linux dir, then I change it for ./
I consider that this means that I will look for libraries in the directory I write: in my case I say it that the libraries is in the same dir. http://iie.fing.edu.uy/~vagonbar/gcc-make/gcc.htm

### First try:

I create make_win.bat with this content (see the .DLL extension):

```
gcc string.c dbf_head.c dbf_ndx.c dbf_misc.c dbf_rec.c luadbase.c
-shared -O2 -Wall -L./ -llua -ldl -lm -lnsl -o dbase.dll


D:\lua-dbase-compiling>make_win

D:\lua-dbase-compiling>gcc string.c dbf_head.c dbf_ndx.c dbf_misc.c dbf_rec.c lu
adbase.c -shared -O2 -Wall -L./ -llua -ldl -lm -lnsl -o dbase.dll
dbf_rec.c: In function 'pack_dbf':
dbf_rec.c:131: warning: implicit declaration of function 'ftruncate'
luadbase.c:20:17: error: lua.h: No such file or directory
luadbase.c:21:21: error: lauxlib.h: No such file or directory
luadbase.c:23:24: error: compat-5.1.h: No such file or directory
luadbase.c:48: error: expected ')' before '*' token
luadbase.c:49: error: expected ')' before '*' token
luadbase.c:50: error: expected ')' before '*' token
luadbase.c:56: error: expected ')' before '*' token
luadbase.c:67: error: expected ')' before '*' token
luadbase.c:77: error: expected ')' before '*' token
luadbase.c:85: error: expected ')' before '*' token
luadbase.c:113: error: expected ')' before '*' token
luadbase.c:120: error: expected ')' before '*' token
luadbase.c:141: error: expected ')' before '*' token
luadbase.c:146: error: expected ')' before '*' token
luadbase.c:151: error: expected ')' before '*' token
luadbase.c:160: error: expected ')' before '*' token
luadbase.c:231: error: expected ')' before '*' token
luadbase.c:398: error: expected ')' before '*' token
luadbase.c:402: error: expected ')' before '*' token
luadbase.c:406: error: expected ')' before '*' token
luadbase.c:428: error: expected ')' before '*' token
luadbase.c:501: error: expected ')' before '*' token
luadbase.c:686: error: expected ')' before '*' token
luadbase.c:700: error: expected ')' before '*' token
luadbase.c:709: error: expected ')' before '*' token
```

As it it saying  that cannot find three files: lua.h, lauxlib.h and compat-5.1.h, then I look for them in m PC. I find them, then copy'em to the dir where I have the sources for DBASE.DLL .

### Second try:

I run make_win.bat with this same content as the first try.

I got a long list of error and warnings. The several first --as you can see in next lines-- indicates me that it could not find the three files I copy.

```
D:\lua-dbase-compiling>make_win

D:\lua-dbase-compiling>gcc string.c dbf_head.c dbf_ndx.c dbf_misc.c dbf_rec.c lu
adbase.c -shared -O2 -Wall -L./ -llua -ldl -lm -lnsl -o dbase.dll
dbf_rec.c: In function 'pack_dbf':
dbf_rec.c:131: warning: implicit declaration of function 'ftruncate'
In file included from luadbase.c:20:
lua.h:16:21: error: luaconf.h: No such file or directory
In file included from luadbase.c:20:
lua.h:99: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'lua_Nu
mber'
lua.h:103: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'lua_I
nteger'
lua.h:110: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'lua_S
tate'
lua.h:111: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'void'

In file included from luadbase.c:21:
lauxlib.h:42: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'vo
id'
lauxlib.h:44: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'vo
id'
lauxlib.h:46: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'in
t'
lauxlib.h:47: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'in
t'

luadbase.c: In function 'luaM_tostring':
luadbase.c:58: warning: implicit declaration of function 'lua_touserdata'
luadbase.c:63: warning: implicit declaration of function 'lua_pushfstring'
luadbase.c:63: warning: implicit declaration of function 'lua_tolstring'
luadbase.c: In function 'luaM_regconst':
luadbase.c:68: warning: implicit declaration of function 'lua_pushstring'
luadbase.c:69: warning: implicit declaration of function 'lua_pushnumber'
luadbase.c:70: warning: implicit declaration of function 'lua_rawset'
luadbase.c: In function 'luaM_setmeta':
luadbase.c:78: warning: implicit declaration of function 'lua_getfield'
```

Then I decided to copy all the sources of Lua v.5.1.4 and the some more for compat-5.1 (that are not in the same sources).

### Third try:

I run make_win.bat with this same content as the first and second try.

The error were a few, in just seven lines.

```
D:\lua-dbase-compiling>gcc string.c dbf_head.c dbf_ndx.c dbf_misc.c dbf_rec.c lu
adbase.c -shared -O2 -Wall -L./ -llua -ldl -lm -lnsl -o dbase.dll
dbf_rec.c: In function 'pack_dbf':
dbf_rec.c:131: warning: implicit declaration of function 'ftruncate'
ld: cannot find -llua
ld: cannot find -ldl
ld: cannot find -lnsl
```

As I am not an expert C programmer, I decided to supress this three arguments: -llua -ldl -lnsl in the runable sentence.

### Forth try:

Now the sentence is:

```
gcc string.c dbf_head.c dbf_ndx.c dbf_misc.c dbf_rec.c luadbase.c -shared -O2 -Wall -L./ -lm -o dbase.dll
```

I got a lot of errors. I got no the first lines:

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccwaAh3E.o:luadbase.c:(.text+0x1f8): undefined
reference to `lua_tolstring'

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccwaAh3E.o:luadbase.c:(.text+0x210): undefined
reference to `lua_tolstring'
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccwaAh3E.o:luadbase.c:(.text+0x220): undefined
reference to`lua_rawset'
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccwaAh3E.o:luadbase.c:(.text+0x230): undefined
reference to `lua_settop'
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccwaAh3E.o:luadbase.c:(.text+0x240): undefined
reference to`lua_next'
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccwaAh3E.o:luadbase.c:(.text+0x254): undefined
reference to `lua_settop'
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccwaAh3E.o:luadbase.c:(.text+0x264): undefined
reference to`lua_objlen'
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccwaAh3E.o:luadbase.c:(.text+0x27e): undefined
reference to `lua_pushboolean'
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccwaAh3E.o:luadbase.c:(.text+0x28e): undefined
reference to`lua_pushstring'
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccwaAh3E.o:luadbase.c:(.text+0x2ac): undefined
reference to `lua_tonumber'
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccwaAh3E.o:luadbase.c:(.text+0x2bf): undefined
reference to`lua_settop'
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccwaAh3E.o:luadbase.c:(.text+0x31b): undefined
reference to `lua_rawgeti'
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccwaAh3E.o:luadbase.c:(.text+0x336): undefined

I do not understand.
I do not see any DLL in the directory.

I do not know how to proceed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks for reading this question.

**HERNAN CANO M.**

Comment: The `-L` flag is to tell where your `lua.h` etc. files are located

Comment: Yes, friend."...in my case I say it that the libraries is in the same dir. "

Comment: In windows, you don't have paths like `./`, instead `.\ `.

Comment: Thanks, potter. I have read that in Windows both ways are acceptable by OS.

Comment: I made the correction suggested by potter.... but the result is the same.